# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I check convergence for this? $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$

I don't think I should be using the series integral test, since we haven't studied it at the lecture. 
I tried using other tests but I can't seem to figure out this one. Anyone have any hints/ideas?

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate. Without computing the sum explicitly, you can simply use $\arctan \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$, and since the series of $1/n^2$ is convergent, so is yours.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$
$$=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:arctan\left(\frac{(n+1)-n}{1+n(n+1)}\right)$$
$$=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left[arctan\left(n+1\right)-arctan\left(n\right)\right]$$

Comment: Oh and the series telescopes then and is convergent! Thank you! :-)